# Is there a way to tell cucumber not to skip other tests in a scenario when a test fail?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

Is there a way to tell cucumber not to skip other tests in a scenario when a test fail?

Comment: Two seconds with Google will show that this is indeed programming related.

Comment: yeah but you didn't answer my question too :P

Answer (score 3):

If one part of a scenario messes up, it generally doesn't make sense to continue.

If you want them to keep going, or they logically make sense to be ran (not coupled with other actions), they probably don't belong in the same scenario

```
Scenario: making a sandwich:
Get bread... Success
Get peanut butter... Success
Get knife... Fail (no knives)
Use knife on peanut butter... errr... what knife?
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience continuing the tests doesn't make any sense.

Could you post an example of your Scenario?